# Is there a fix for Skyrim crashing to the desktop when looking at a large gem pile?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I'm finding a lot of gems in dungeons, recently, and so I've decided to fill my basement room with them.

I've gotten quite a lot, and after dropping the last haul, I've found myself in the unfortunate situation, that Skyrim crashes to desktop, everytime I look in the pile's direction.

Even with the door to the room closed, it still dies horribly.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I was hoping for an epic look, gem pile, and I am still far from that.

This happened both before, and after, the 1.3 patch.

Comment: Most likely because you got a x64 os. For whatever reason Bethesda figured it would be awesome if Skyrim was locked to the maximum use of 2gb ram. This causes the game to crash every time Skyrim is in need of more than 2gb of ram. My word of advise, do not update. Skyrim worked better without these back alley made patches.

Comment: i want to do this as well, and placing them on your bed would make it more awesome because you would be like a dragon sleeping on its hoard(why don't skyrim dragons have hoards?)

Comment: @Havoc - What exactly does having a 64-bit OS have to do with the 2gb limit? Nothing.

Comment: Your gems don't disappear after a few days??

Comment: @Rachel, I don't think so. I certainly hope not. I'm pretty sure, some of them have been there for more than a few days.

Comment: @Rachel: items in your house don't disappear, ever.  That's basically what your house is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted at by @Havoc, a possible solution is the Large Address Aware patch that was made. However, this patch does not function with the latest 1.3 version of Skyrim. It is entirely likely that Skyrim is crashing because it needs more than the hard-locked 2 gigs of ram and using this user-made patch will allow Skyrim to access more ram (assuming your computer actually has more).

There might be other versions, but a quick search brought me to this [patch](http://www.fileplanet.com/223467/220000/fileinfo/Elder-Scrolls-V:-Skyrim---4GB-Skyrim-Mod-v1.4) on Fileplanet.

Hopefully, Bethesda will actually fix this issue themselves rather than making us rely on user-made fixes, but who knows.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't make any difference :(

Comment: Bethesda is working on an official LAA patch... they're looking at releasing it next week. Source: http://www.bethblog.com/2011/12/07/skyrim-update-1-3-now-on-steam/